# Is it possible for a Cassandra node to go down while performing a very large compaction?

Tags: cassandra

I have a three Cassandra node cluster with a 4TB disk each and an average of approximately 1TB of used space in each node. Additionally I am using `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy`.

My problem is that a node went down while performing a very large compaction (1.6TB), hence **my question is** whether such large compaction could be the cause.

The reason for my suspicion is the recommendation in Cassandra's documentation regarding disk size: [we should limit node's disk size capacity to 1TB](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cassandra/Hardware).

Thanks for your attention

Comment: It could have gone down with out of memory in which case you should be able to see the oom killer in the os system logs doing this.

Comment: Can you show the actual system log error messages as it went down?

Comment: unfortunately the logs are not available anymore, but there wre quite a lot gc.logs